# Can I put the result from kibana to elasicsearch again?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Can I put the response result that I query in Kibana dev tools into elasticsearch directly?

Or must I write a script to achieve it?
Any recommends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So here is one basic understanding after discussion.

Please observe carefully.
If you have head plugin  installed for ES .
search for .kibana index .
open the .kibana index and you will have all the designed dashboards listed there with processd info.

Think ES as another Storage from where you can read the data and put that data into Another ES index.

Refer to this link :
https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-under-the-hood-object-persistence

Tools you can opt is Logstash for Reading and writing.
Grok pattern learning can give you good lead about that.
Tell me if need some real time pics for same problem.
Happy learning.

Comment: I am very grateful to you. I think I will benefit a lot from your suggestions. I am reading documents.Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

It is like you cook in kitchen and ask to put the cooked food in kitchen again.If you cooked food better consume it :)

See the visualization or processed data you see on kibana end is just for kibana.The algorithms or processing techniques for the data set residing at elastic search will be applied over the upcoming data set.

So offcourse you can put/consume your data in Elastic search back again.
It depends what sort of requirement you are facing.

Note : Data in elastic search(inverted index) after kibana processing not gonna change its architecture, due to which you are able to apply another processing techniques from kibana over the same index assuming that data is in it's earlier state.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you give me some guide document? I have no idea. I want to put the response data into another index. So I can process it in another way.

Comment: Please tell me  how you ingested raw data first time into your elastic search index ?
Are able to see the processed data in json/CSV/any format after kibana processing ?

Comment: `{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "test",
  "_id": "eacc1448-30de-457f-bd9a-20dd9240f6db",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "updateat": "2011-05-03T17:30:08Z",
    "user_id": 41
  },
  "fields": {
    "updateat": [
      "2011-05-03T17:30:08.000Z"
    ]
  }
}`   This is my raw data

Comment: And my query  is `GET /test/test/_search
{
   "size" : 0,
   "aggs": {
      "day_count": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
         }
      }
      
   }
}
`  ,

Comment: I wan to put the response data into another index in elasticsearch.

Comment: Are you able to get the json/csv/any other format of kibana processed data ?
The resultant data of kibana is to be stored in .kibana index if you can visualise it .